# Java SocketException Broken pipe

Tags: java, sockets

I am doing a client to server Log-in communication.

I met a java.net.SocketException: broke Pipe at Server end. And I have narrowed the 
problem to **one single line at the client end**. If I move a position for this line,
the code works. plese see the following code.

Client End:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket(Const.destIp, 12101);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(this.message);              
    out.close();//Line that cause problem   
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    ServerToClientLogin msg = (ServerToClientLogin) in.readObject();
    //out.close();//move it to here, problem solved
    in.close();
    socket.close();
```

Server end:

```
   while (true) {
     socket = _serverSocket.accept();
     in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     msg = (ClientToServerLogin) in.readObject();

     ServerToClientLogin msgToSend = null;
     out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     msgToSend = handleLoginRequest(msg);
     if(msgToSend != null) out.writeObject(msgToSend);

     try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
     try { out.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
     try { socket.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Since readObject and writeObject are blocking call, I have no idea why close it earlier would case such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out.close();`: Closes this (`out`) output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream.

See the API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29).

Comment: out is of type ObjectOutputStream, calling out.close() would close its socket?

Comment: Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream, that's in the API

Comment: @PbxMan add what you said to the answer, it'll make it clearer.

Comment: @PbxMan For clarity, yes it closes the socket, also its input stream. Closing any one of those three closes the other two.